# Is there a way to add NaN values based on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two data frames:
Original:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  9.0
```

Imputation:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

(both are the same dataframes except imputation has the NaN's filled in).

I would like to reintroduce the NaN values into the imputation df column A so it looks like this(column B, C are filled in but A keeps the NaN values):

```
#      A    B    C
# 0  NaN  4.0  7.0
# 1  2.0  5.0  8.0
# 2  NaN  6.0  9.0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfImputation = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

dfOrginal = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.NaN,2,np.NaN],
                   'B':[4,5,np.NaN],
                   'C':[7,np.NaN,9]})


print(dfOrginal.fillna(dfImputation))
```

I do not get the result I want because it just obviously fills in all values. There is a way to introduce NaN values or a way to fill in NA for specific columns? I'm not quite sure the best approach to get the intended outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill in only specified columns by subsetting the frame you pass into the `fillna` operation:

```py
>>> dfOrginal.fillna(dfImputation[["B", "C"]])
     A    B    C
0  NaN  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `update`

```
df.update(im[['B','C']])
df
Out[7]: 
     A    B    C
0  NaN  4.0  7.0
1  2.0  5.0  8.0
2  NaN  6.0  9.0
```